# `git rebase` entire branch-tree

Tags: git, merge, branching-and-merging

I have two unrelated "parts" in my git repository, one of which contains merges:

```
  X---Y

        A---B---C
       /         \
  D---E---F---G---H
```

Now `Y` and `D` contain exactly the same filesm (think of the 2 parts as a single disjoint history)

I would like to rebase the entire second part (`D..H`) onto the first part, so i get something like

```
                A---B---C
               /         \
  X---Y---D---E---F---G---H
```

Unfortunately doing a simple `git rebase` only works for single branches, and will flatten the history and lose the branching/merging parts.

How can i rebase an entire "branch-tree"?

### background

the code was originally developped using subversion.
at some point I switched to git for implementing experimental features, but just started off the last state of the svn-repository (rather than doing a proper svn2git conversion).
the git history includes branching, merging and things.

I would now like to switch over to `git` entirely, but would also like to combine both histories into a single one (including all merges).

Comment: This has almost the same example as yours: http://ben.straubnet.net/post/939181602/git-grafting-repositories

Comment: Hi @umläute, did you try this: 
1. git checkout branch_D_to_H; 
2. git pull --rebase origin branch_x_y?

Comment: @Phoebe there is no remote (e.g. `origin`), this is all a single local repository with disjoint branches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that the `rebase` command has some options to preserve branches (most important `--preserve-merges`:

```
git checkout d--h
git rebase --root  --preserve-merges --onto x--y
```

This will give me exactly what i wanted.

(As expected) it does not migrate any tags nor umerged branches.
So to rebase the following `D`-based subtree (note that this contains two unmerged branches) onto `Y`,...

```
  X---Y

        A---B---C
       /
  D---E---F---G---H
```

..., you need multiple calls to `git rebase`:

```
git checkout branch-to-h
git rebase --root  --preserve-merges --onto x--y
git checkout branch-to-c
git rebase --root  --preserve-merges --onto x--y
```

which results in:

```
            A---B---C
           /
  X---Y---D---E---F---G---H
```